# rake aborted - cannot load such file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I recently upgrade the Rspec Gem in my Ruby project from 2.12.0 to 2.99.2. Before I did the upgrade everything works just fine, but once I upgrade to 2.99.2 and run one of my spec test, there is a "rake aborted - cannot load such file error" pop up. The error message said it cannot load support/ext/vcr, which is another rb file I require in the spec file, any idea about that?

```
  rake aborted!

   cannot load such file -- support/ext/vcr



   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

 # ./spec/integration/resque_integration_spec.rb:31:in `rescue in wait_for'

 # ./spec/integration/resque_integration_spec.rb:22:in `wait_for'

 # ./spec/integration/resque_integration_spec.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:116:in `block in run'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:248:in `with_around_each_hooks'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:113:in `run'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:515:in `block in run_examples'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:511:in `map'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:511:in `run_examples'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:496:in `run'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in run'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `map'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block in run'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:103:in `run'

 # /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.99.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating, you should always restart your development environment. See if doing that helps at all.

Comment: Hi Collin, I restarted my development environment but it is still the same error. I am wondering if there any syntax change (e.g deprecated syntax) from 2.12 to 2.14+ because this error only happened after upgrading to 2.14 or later version. In 2.12 or 2.13 everything runs well.

Comment: Hi Chris-

Version 2.99.x certainly has deprecations (see link provided), but the worst that would do is have your system yell at your for using a deprecated method. You won't see substantial breaking changes until you upgrade to Version 3.x.x of Rspec. Will you update your question to provide more code context? It's hard to know what's going on from such an ambiguous error message.

Here's the link to Rspec's changes: http://rspec.info/blog/2013/11/rspec-2-99-and-3-0-betas-have-been-released/

(Edited to add link)